# Docusign 'Generate Document' (File) 'owner' should be who generating the document

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

For example, User A is generating the document, the document generated successfully and saved in the file related list.

But the owner of the file is who installed the app instead of User A.

Please let me know where its to be configured.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

@Rkumar I would see it from a different perspective. The sender of the envelope can download the document from the app through the API and Web console. The signer once they sign and envelope status changes to complete will receive email containing completed envelope. The signer then can download the completed envelope as well. If  you are providing integration solution the accounts you created for the user should be the owners of the documents

Comment: Thanks, @IvanD. I'm using Docusign Gen in SF. If I'm generate the document, the generated docusign document gets stored under Files related list. If User B generating the document, but the owner of the file is User A (docusign admin)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> But the owner of the file is who installed the app instead of User A.

If the file is downloaded by an app, then it is up to the app who the owner of the file is on the operating system (the file system).

But operating systems usually make it difficult for an app operated by user A to produce files that show user B as the owner.

In any case, you need to discuss with the person who wrote the application.

Comment: Thanks, @Larry. I'm using Docusign Gen in SF. If I'm generate the document, the generated docusign document gets stored under Files related list.